# How to Initialize any integer in python without using "0" or "None"

Tags: python

If I input:

-1 -1 0 -9 -2 -2

-2 -1 -6 -8 -2 -5

-1 -1 -1 -2 -3 -4

-1 -9 -2 -4 -4 -5

-7 -3 -3 -2 -9 -9

-1 -3 -1 -2 -4 -5

then as Result is initialized 0 so max hourglass output I get is 0 while it should be -6.

Also, tried "Result=None" but that didn't work in max function as other parameter(sum) is an integer.

sum=0

result=0

```
for i in range(4):

    for j in range(4):

        sum = (arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2])+ (arr[i+1][j+1])+ (arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2])

        result=max(sum,result)
```

print(result)

## As every sum computed is negative so Result's initial Value 0 gives the answer while the correct answer is -6 as out of every Hourglass possible -6 sum is the max we got.

## Initializing it with a certain value like -100 would not give efficient solution as when input data is changed and all the sums are less than -100 then we would get -100 as the max Output which is wrong.

Comment: `result = float('-inf')` ?

Comment: Which value are you trying to initialize? Also, the formatting of your post looks broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize result with None and check for None in the loop:

```
result = sum if result is None else max(sum,result)
```

Ideally you should use the max function on the whole structure through an iterator

```
def cellSum(i,j): return arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2])+ (arr[i+1][j+1])+ (arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2])

result = max( cellSum(i,j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4) )
```